# Access Violation/Heap Corruption during new char

Tags: c++

I've a C++ code sample that I can't explain why it randomly causes the app to fail with either an access violation or heap corruption. I know the sample contains code that is currently frown upon (working directly with pointers to char), but this is just for learning purposes. If anyone could take a look over the code and let me know if you see something that I'm missing, I'd very much appreciate it. Thanks.

```
class Operand
{
private:
    double value;
    char* message;
public:
    Operand(double value);
    ~Operand();
    char* operator+(const Operand& other);
};

Operand::Operand(double value)
{
    this->value = value;
}

char* Operand::operator+(const Operand& other)
{
    char s[256];
    double sum = this->value + other.value;
    sprintf_s(s, "The sum of %f and %f is %f", this->value, other.value, sum);
    this->message = new char[strlen(s)];  //this is where it sometimes crashes with an access violation
    strcpy_s(this->message, sizeof(s), s);
    return this->message;
}

Operand::~Operand()
{
    if (this->message != nullptr)
        delete[] this->message;
}

int main()
{
    double operand1, operand2;
    cout << "Please input the calculator parameters: operand1 operand2: ";
    cin >> operand1 >> operand2;

    auto Operand1 = Operand(operand1);
    auto Operand2 = Operand(operand2);
    char* message1 = Operand1 + Operand2;
    char* message2 = Operand2 + Operand1;
    cout << message1 << "\n";
    cout << message2 << "\n";

    return 0; //and sometimes it crashes right after outputting to cout
}
```

I don't see why the two char* message pointers would interfere with each other, since they belong to different Operand instances. If that is indeed the cause of it. Or maybe I'm missing something.

I'd really appreciate a second pair of eyes, as I'm out of ideas. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple bugs that will result in memory corruption.

The other answers already mentioned the insufficient memory allocation. But that's the least of your problems.

## Uninitialized pointer

`Operand`'s constructor fails to initialize the `message` member. The destructor will then likely attempt to `delete` a pointer that was never newed.

## Rule Of 3/5 violation

The shown class [violates the Rule Of The Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three). At the minimum, it also needs a proper copy constructor, and an assignment operator.

## `operator+` leaks memory

This will result in a memory leak, due to the failure to `delete` the existing contents of `message`, if it was already allocated.

These are all the bugs that were immediately apparent, after a cursory review of the code. There are probably a couple more.

Comment: Thanks for the good feedback. I realize that there may be multiple best practices being broken in my sample, but it's mainly for learning purposes. It's not meant to be perfectly designed. But I really appreciate your pointers.

Comment: About the uninitialized pointer, if I initialize it to nullptr, that should make the issue go away, right? Since I'm already checking for nullptr before delete-ing

Comment: Yes, that will address that specific issue.

Comment: About the operator+ leaking memory, are you sure? Again, I realize it may be a very unorthodox code sample (again, for learning purposes), but I do attempt to free memory in the destructor.

Comment: What happens when you invoke `operator+` a second time?

Comment: Oh, I think I get it. You mean a second time on the same object. I don't have that being done yet, in this sample. But it's a very good point. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You need to allocate an extra byte for the terminating null:

```
this->message = new char[strlen(s) + 1];
```

Comment: Thanks, I missed that. And it seems I also had another issue right after the allocation. In the strcpy_s call, I was specifying an incorrect sizeinbytes. Specifying strlen(s)+1 made the memory violation go away

Answer (score 1):

In `operator+`, you are creating place for a new string with`new char[strlen(s)]`. That is one character short; you need to have space for the final `'\0'`.

When you then copy the string into it, the `'\0'` overwrites the next byte in memory, which leads to undefined behavior.

Comment: @M.M , that's what I said... silly iPad doesn't listen... Thanks.